# The module below have been removed from Gradle structure

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Trying new Android studio got the following message

[image]

What changed and in which files I have to make to include the modules in the Gradle structure.

Comment: I get this if I try to move a project outside of the C:\users\username\androidstudioprojects\ directory - it looks like some paths are hard-coded in the android studio settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of gradle modules is define in `gradle.settings` file (at the root of your project). So check this file to see if it's still valid. It must contains something like:

```
include :CheckAndroidStudio
```

Additionally, you can check the `build.gradle` files to see if they are valid scripts and if they define the android plugin. (i.e. `apply plugin: 'android'`)

Take a look at [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Simple-build-files) to find the minimal configuration for an Android app.

According my understanding project configuration in Android Studio is completely driven by those files.